# Как правильно: дефектовать или дефектоскопировать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Дефектоскопирование, или неразрушающий контроль, – это комплекс мероприятий, направленных на выявление скрытых, наружных или внутренних дефектов в изделии производственного или эксплуатационного характера (трещины, поры, непровары и т.д.).

Как правильно: **дефектовать** ось колёсной пары или **дефектоскопировать** ось колёсной пары?

Answer (score 4):

Это разные по значению слова. **Дефектоскопировать** - производить поиск дефектов в техническом объекте при помощи технологического оборудования дефектоскопии (например, ультразвуковой, лазерной и т. п. - с визуализацией дефектов). **Дефектовать** - принимать решение о наличии дефекта в исследуемом каким-либо способом (включая простейший осмотр) объекте и (как правило) документально фиксировать факт его обнаружения.